# Ubuntu Server - Make `lastlog` show the hostname rather than the IP address

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

When logging into Ubuntu Server via SSH, the following line is shown:

`Last login: Mon Jul 18 20:00:00 2016 from 111.111.111.111`

On other serves, `111.111.111.111` is replaced by the hostname `me.domain.com`, as my rDNS is setup correctly.

How do I configure this Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server to do the same?

Answer (score 3):

Open your sshd_config file and ensure this

```
UseDNS yes
```

After that, restart your ssh server. I try this in Centos 7 and the IP become hostname.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This works just fine here in the year 2020 for both IPv4 and IPv6 on Ubuntu Server 18.04 (Bionic) AND Debian 9 (Stretch)

Comment: glad to see it still help for now :)

Answer (score 1):

**PAM generates that line of text due to the following configuration line in `/etc/pam.d/login`**

```
# Prints the last login info upon succesful login
# (Replaces the `LASTLOG_ENAB' option from login.defs)
session    optional   pam_lastlog.so
```

There are some configuration options you can pass to that pam module, but I see nothing about resolving hostnames. /var/log/lastlog is where the info you are seeing is stored and this file stores IP addresses, not hostnames. This makes sense from a security standpoint I think. I checked some of the source code too... I couldn't find anything obvious about resolving IP addresses (at least not in pam_lastlog.c). Maybe it's hidden somewhere else and I missed it.

**This perl script will use `lastlog` to print the last login information for the current user and will resolve IPv4 addresses into hostnames**

You could add it to your `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` or under `/etc/update-motd.d/`, etc... to get the same effect. It's not perfectly formatted, so you may need to fiddle with it to make it look the way you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use Socket;

open(my $lastLogOut,"lastlog -u $ENV{LOGNAME} |");

while(my $entry = ) {
        chomp($entry);
        my $ipAddress;
        my $hostname;

        if($entry =~ /(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/) {
                $ipAddress = $&;
                if($hostname = gethostbyaddr(inet_aton($ipAddress), AF_INET)) { 
                        $entry =~ s/$ipAddress/$hostname/g;
                }
        }

        print $entry."\n";

}
```

**Sample output**

```
$ perl lastlog.dns 
Username         Port     From             Latest
ryan         pts/5    localhost        Mon Jul 18 22:26:28 -0400 2016
```

**If you want to use the above script during login**, you may want to stop PAM from printing out last login information. Append `silent` to the pam_lastlog line in `/etc/pam.d/login`.

```
session    optional   pam_lastlog.so silent
```

Answer (score 1):

A more detailed version of [@akhfa's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/790899/262070):

Open up the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in a text editor, such as `nano` or `vim`

```sh
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Towards the bottom of the file, you should find this (it's okay if you don't see it)

```
#UseDNS no
```

If you find this, simply un-comment the line by removing the `#` from the start:

```
UseDNS yes
```

If you can't find `UseDNS` anywhere in the file, simply add a **new line to the bottom of the file** containing `UseDNS yes` (like above).

Save and close the file.

Restart the OpenSSH service. On Ubuntu, you can use `systemctl`:

```sh
sudo systemctl restart ssh
# On some systems, it may be under openssh-server
sudo systemctl restart openssh-server
```

Now, to ensure you haven't potentially been locked out of SSH, open a **new, separate SSH connection**, and connect to the system in question. (if you can't connect, you broke your SSH config, run `systemctl status ssh` - fix your config / search for how to fix it while you still have a working SSH connection open)

You should now see:

```
Last login: Mon Jan 1 20:00:00 2020 from 111.111.111.111
```

If you re-connect or open yet another SSH connection, you should now see your hostname from the previous connection (assuming the IP you're connecting from has **Reverse DNS**)

```
Last login: Mon Jan 1 20:00:00 2020 from some.host.example.com
```

**This answer was tested on both Ubuntu Server 18.04 (Bionic Beaver), and Debian 9 (Stretch) on 21 / JAN / 2020 - this answer may or may not work depending on your Linux distribution / OpenSSH version**